# Sharepoint Alternatives?

Tags: sharepoint

Can anyone recommend any cloud based alternatives too SharePoint? I have seen a couple good ones on sites like www.sharepointalternative.com and www.topsharepointalternatives.com but does anyone have experience of ones they have used before?

We are a small company of 16 people but are looking to expand to around 30 by the end of the year and so should be easily scalable. We would need to be able to easily share and edit files and have a version control.

It also has to work as an internal and external portal as we want to share with clients as well as internally.

Comment: "microsoft enterprise collaboration alternatives" is not a tag.

Comment: Not really an answer, but this could be done with Dropbox. It would only be able to match the document library part of Sharepoint (and includes version control).

Comment: You can try Communifire, a product of my company (Axero Solutions) which is more user friendly than Sharepoint and also has a lot of similar features.

Answer (score 2):

Check out http://www.alfresco.com/.  We tried it, but it was not a good solution for us since we have hundreds of users and our groups needed many sub-sites with their own permissions.

Answer (score 0):

google apps for sure!
http://www.ilovefreesoftware.com/09/articles/sharepoint-vs-google-apps.html

It's free up until 20 users I believe. So you can easily try it out without extra costs and than pay a little if you expand enough

Answer (score 0):

CMSWire has a great list of [Sharepoint Alternatives](http://www.cmswire.com/cms/enterprise-cms/sharepoint-portal-alternatives-a-credible-list-005080.php). [Glasscubes](http://www.glasscubes.com/features/) seems to be the most viable alternative for what you are looking for, however I have zero experience with it.